# Массив кинотеатр

Tags: delphi, pascal

Доброго времени суток имеется задание:
В кинотеатре n рядов по m мест в каждом (m и n должно задаваться с клавиатуры). В двумерном массиве размерностью m на n хранится информация о проданных билетах. Число 1 означает, что билет на данное место уже продан, число 0 означает, что место свободно. **Поступил запрос на продажу k билетов на соседние места в одном ряду (k должно задаваться с клавиатуры). Определить, можно ли выполнить такой запрос. Если решения есть, вывести номера рядов и номера свободных мест для продажи. Число занятых мест и какие места заняты на момент запроса определите случайным образом.**
Вывести исходный массив на экран.

Первую часть задания вроде сделал с вводом запроса тоже разобрался не пойму как сделать вот это *Определить, можно ли выполнить такой запрос. Если решения есть, вывести номера рядов и номера свободных мест для продажи.*

```
  program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const s=50;
var
a:array [1..s,1..s] of integer;
i, j, n, m, k, mL, fL:integer;
begin
randomize;
writeln('Vvedite kol-vo strok i stolbcov');
readln (n, m);
write('massiv:');
writeln;
for i:=1 to n do
 for j:=1 to m do
  a[i,j]:=random (2)-0;
for i:=1 to n do
begin
 for j:=1 to m do
 write (a[i,j]:5);
 writeln;
end;
 writeln('Vvedite zapros');
 Readln(k);
  i := 0;
  repeat
    Inc(i);
    mL := 0; fL := 0;
    for j := 1 to m do
      if a[i, j] = 0 then
        Inc(fL)
      else
        begin
          if fL > mL then mL := fL;
          fL := 0;
        end;
    if fL > mL then mL := fL;
  until (i = n) or (mL >= k);

  if mL < k then WriteLn(0) else WriteLn('Riad s naibolshim kol-vom svobodnbIx mest: ', i);
readln;
end.
```

Пока смог сделать такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика после `Readln(k);` может быть такой:

(добавил оптимизацию, предложенную Владимиром)

```
for i:=1 to n do begin
  last_occupied :=  0;
  for j:=1 to m + 1 do
     if (j > m) or (a[i, j] = 1) then begin
          if j - last_occupied - 1 >= k then
              writeln(i, ':', last_occupied + 1, '..', j-1);
          last_occupied := j;
          if j > m - k then break; 
       end;
 end;
```

Пример работы для k=3

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
row 1 3..7
row 4 1..3
row 4 5..8
row 5 1..3
row 8 2..6
```

Comment: `for j:=1 to m do` Зачем? 
Почему не так :`for j:=1 to m-k do` ?

Comment: @Владимир Клыков А что может позволить не проверять последние места в ряду?

Comment: Наверное то что бессмысленно проверять последние `k-1` мест? ибо даже если все `k-1` свободны а место `m-k` занято - ровно ноль смысла проверять места которых явно нехватает для **подряд свободных k мест**

Comment: Хотя кажется понял что не давало покоя, проверять надо до m, но нужен break если `m-k` занято.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Идею понял, но это оптимизация, которая не отменяет проверки в хорошем случае для получения конечных свободных мест.

Comment: да я уже понял где немного затупил, и что проверять их иногда придется.