# Можете объяснить часть кода

Tags: delphi, pascal

Нужно объяснить код.
Текст задания:
В кинотеатре n рядов по m мест в каждом (m и n должно задаваться с клавиатуры). В двумерном массиве размерностью m на n хранится информация о проданных билетах. Число 1 означает, что билет на данное место уже продан, число 0 означает, что место свободно. Поступил запрос на продажу k билетов на соседние места в одном ряду (k должно задаваться с клавиатуры). Определить, можно ли выполнить такой запрос. Если решения есть, вывести номера рядов и номера свободных мест для продажи. Число занятых мест и какие места заняты на момент запроса определите случайным образом.
Вывести исходный массив на экран.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const s=50;
var
a:array [1..s,1..s] of integer;
lst_occ, i, j, n, m, k:integer;
begin
randomize;
writeln('Vvedite kol-vo strok i stolbcov');
readln (n, m);
write('massiv:');
writeln;
for i:=1 to n do
 for j:=1 to m do
  a[i,j]:=random (2)-0;
for i:=1 to n do
begin
 for j:=1 to m do
 write (a[i,j]:5);
 writeln;
end;
 writeln('Vvedite zapros');
 Readln(k);
  for i:=1 to n do 
  begin
  lst_occ :=  0;
  for j:=1 to m+1  do
     if (j > m) or (a[i, j] = 1) then
        begin
          if j - lst_occ - 1 >= k then
              writeln('Row ', i, ': ', ' s ',lst_occ + 1, ' po ', j-1, ' mesta svobodnbI');
          lst_occ := j;
          if j > m - k then break;
      end;
 end;
readln;
end.
```

Вот эту часть кода:

```
Readln(k);
  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
  lst_occ :=  0;
  for j:=1 to m + 1 do (почему тут m+1, а не m просто)
     if (j > m) or (a[i, j] = 1) then (что проверяет этот оператор конкретно по отношению в массиве)
        begin
          if j - lst_occ - 1 >= k then (что проверяет этот оператор в массиве)
              writeln('Row ', i, ': ', ' s ',lst_occ + 1, ' po ', j-1, ' mesta svobodnbI'); (почему тут lst_occ + 1, а не просто lst_occ, j-1, а не просто j)
          if j > m - k then break; (что проверяет этот оператор в массиве)
      end;
 end;
```

Comment: Кажется, у меня дежавю

Comment: Что мешало спросить об этих нюансах еще [9 ноября](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904517/Массив-кинотеатр)?

Comment: да забыл сорян навалилось других дел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for j:=1 to m + 1 do (почему тут m+1, а не m просто)
    if (j > m) or (a[i, j] = 1) then 
  (что проверяет этот оператор конкретно по отношению в массиве)
```

Потому что нужно проверять длину свободной серии, когда заканчивается ряд (случай m+1, j>m) и когда встретим занятое место (a[i, j] = 1)

```
   writeln('Row ', i, ': ', ' s ',lst_occ + 1, ' po ', j-1, ' mesta svobodnbI'); 
  (почему тут lst_occ + 1, а не просто lst_occ, j-1, а не просто j)
```

Потому что выводится промежуток с первого **свободного** места по последнее **свободное**

```
    if j > m - k then break; 
 (что проверяет этот оператор в массиве)
```

это описано в комментариях В.Клыкова - если место j занято, а за ним уже осталось менее k мест, проверять дальше не стоит